# Can you cache blocks per language?

Tags: blocks, i18n-l10n

I am working on a multilingual site right now, and am using the [Internationalization](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) suite of modules to build it out.

The site has some custom blocks in it that I would normally use [`DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/constant/DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL/7) in the [`hook_block_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) definition.  However, some of these will have [translatable strings](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) in them, so I really need to cache them per-language.

Is this possible?  Or, is my only real option to use [`DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/constant/DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE/7)?

Comment: Could you use [DRUPAL_CACHE_CUSTOM](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/constant/DRUPAL_CACHE_CUSTOM/7)? I've not had much experience with multilingual sites, but I suppose in theory you could cache the content in a custom language based cache (e.g. `cache_set`/`cache_get` with `mpd_awesome_site_fr`, `mpd_awesome_site_ru`)

Comment: @Chapabu I am considering that.  I have just seen very little use of it in the wild (the core forum module is the only place I have ever seen it), so I don't really know how much of a "best practice" it is.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/cultuurnet/cnapi/blob/master/cnapi_extras/cnapi_extras.module) module on GitHub seems to do some multilingual block caching stuff of it's own - don't know if it's helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL`. On multilingual sites the users language is part of the (`cid`), i.e. the key used when storing/fetching entries to/from the block cache.

The function responsible for this behavior is [drupal_render_cid_parts](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render_cid_parts/7) which is called from [_block_get_cache_id](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/_block_get_cache_id/7).

You can embed the following fragment into a custom PHP block in order to verify the mechanism:

```
$fakeblock = (object) array(
  'module' => 'some-module',
  'delta' => 'some-delta',
  'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL,
);
print _block_get_cache_id($fakeblock);
```

On a multilingual site, the fragment should print something like:

> some-module:some-delta:bartik:en

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't catch that when I traced everything out the first time.